# Use iterable on Collection<? super T>

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, wildcard

I am new to wildcards and am having an issue iterating through a Collection type. I had to transform this function to work on any Collection type, not just List and here is what I did:

```
    void sell(List<T> items) {
       for (T e : items) {
         stock.add(e);
       }
    }
```

changed to:

```
     void sell(Collection<? super T> items) {

        Iterator ir = items.iterator();

        while (ir.hasNext()){
            stock.add((T)ir.next());
        }
    }
```

However, when I compile the code I receive the errors:

```
Note: Shop.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Am I not using iterable correctly? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no reason to use foreach loop in one and not the other. `Collection` (and even more generally, `Iterable`) can be used with foreach loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, since you are fetching items from the collection, you should use `? extends T` instead of `? super T`.

Secondly, you should use parameterized `Iterator`, and not raw type. That is why you are getting that warning.

Change your method to:

```
void sell(Collection<? extends T> items) {

    Iterator<? extends T> ir = items.iterator();

    while (ir.hasNext()){
        stock.add(ir.next());
    }
}
```

You can still use the original `for` loop with `Collection<? extends T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't define T in the class. So you have to add parameterized type to this class. Here is the modified class line:

```
public class YourClassName<T> // add <T> as parameterized type
```

I purpose this will work for you at all.
Get more information of generic type, just take a look at [Generic Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).